# Sum of the lengths of a string array using Java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I've written this code that doesn't compile:

```
String[] text = {"hello", "bye"};
IntStream.of(Arrays.stream(text).map(String::length)).sum()
```

Do I need to convert the stream to an IntStream? And why do I get an error when I pass `String::length` to the `map()` function?

Comment: Try this `.map(String::length).reduce(0,(m1,m2)->m1+m2);`

Comment: How about `String.join("", text).length()`? Less efficient but more concise.

Comment: @HadiJ Depends what the expected result is.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use [`Stream.mapToInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) in order to get an `IntStream` instance:

```
String[] text = {"hello", "bye"};
int total = Arrays.stream(text).mapToInt(String::length).sum();
```

Comment: what if you concat them all together, and *then* do a `.length`

Comment: @Eugene Yeah, that should work, too. However it would duplicate memory usage. If there are many strings, maybe this way is better.

Comment: maybe, I don't know either which will be faster, if that is important at all

Comment: @Eugene Well, to be honest, more than optimizing for speed or memory usage, I don't *feel* that creating a new `String` instance would be entirely correct, when all you want is the total length. Concatenating all the strings to find out the final length would be like getting married several times to check if your mother-in-law is a good woman. You'd better find out about your future mother-in-law before proposing to your girlfriend...

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffner You edit about `IntStream` is misleading I think. This one is valid : `Integer reduce = Arrays.stream(text)
                               .map(String::length)
                               .reduce(0, Integer::sum);`. The `mapToInt()` is for avoiding to box and then unbox `int`s.

Comment: @davidxxx I edited mainly to add the link to the docs, and I reworded the sentence. Maybe it is not clear?

Comment: Sorry I didn't detail enough. I find the edit misleading because the OP uses `map(String::length)` and you you stress  on `mapToInt()` as solution. It gives the feeling that it was the issue while it is an optimization. And sorry it is not the edit but it was also present in the original answer.

Comment: @davidxxx Correct, now I get it. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: If you want a truly different alternative, you may consider `Arrays.stream(text).flatMapToInt(String::chars).count()`, but your solution is the best, as long as counting all chars (`char` aka UTF-16 unit) is intended. It becomes more interesting when counting code points (`Arrays.stream(text).flatMapToInt(String::codePoints).count()` or actual characters (is there actually a solution?)…

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Arrays.stream(text)
      .filter(Objects::nonNull)
      .mapToInt(String::length)
      .reduce(0,Integer::sum);
```

Comment: of course you would want to use a method reference `0, Integer::sum`, but than it is an exact duplicate of @davidxxx, which in turn is a duplicate or @Federico (`sum` does the same thing internally)

Comment: All those who score above 125 have allowed a down vote. But recommend that you write down the reason.

Comment: @Eugene 121 on 6,244. Indeed you never did. God bless you :)

Comment: @Hadi J I was also downvoted. It is the game. Good answers are generally upvoted. Less good are sometimes downvoted.

Comment: I haven't downvoted either. I downvote only if the answer is clearly wrong, and this is not the case. Besides, you are checking for `null`, which is absolutely correct.

Comment: I didn't downvote but you answer has some defects. `.map(String::length)` returns an `Integer` and you sum them in `reduce()`, which produces unboxing for each Integer. Besides, the method reference to sum `int`s is really more readable.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to convert the stream to an IntStream?

Well, you don't *need* to in order to find the total length of all the strings but *it's better* to do so for performance reasons.

> And why do I get an error when I pass String::length to the map()
>   function?

If you change the method reference to a lambda, you'll get a better hint at what is wrong. i.e.

```
 IntStream.of(Arrays.stream(text).map(e -> e.length())).sum();
```

Now, you don't only have a squiggly line near the `map` function but also under the `IntStream.of` method. After hovering over the `of` method on an IDE, I get the message:

> `"cannot resolve method of(java.util.stream.Stream<R>)"`

Now, this tells us that we're passing the wrong thing to the `of` method. There are two overloads of the `of` method:

> `of(int... values)`
>
> `of(int t)`

As you can see these two methods expect either a set of values to be passed or a single value to be passed, being of type `int`.

Clearly, the `IntStream.of` method is not our friend, in this case, rather we will want:

```
int length = Arrays.stream(text) // Stream<String>
                   .mapToInt(String::length)  //IntStream
                   .sum(); // int
```

This approach simply maps each string to its length and sums them all up.