# Java stream API to find length of each string in list

Tags: java, arrays, string, java-stream

I have a String array in java as follows.

```
String[] text = {"hello", "bye"};
```

Now I need to use Java stream API to calculate the length of each string in this array. I do not want to use for loop. How can I do that?

Update:
I have checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49438006/6379197) and got the following code to get the sum of the length of each string of this array.

```
Arrays.stream(text)
      .filter(Objects::nonNull)
      .mapToInt(String::length)
      .reduce(0,Integer::sum);
```

Comment: what is the final goal ? You said "length of each string in this array" but your code computes a sum. What is the exact expected result ?

Answer (score 6):

## tl;dr

Use code points rather than `char` & `String#length`.

```java
Arrays
    .stream( inputs )                          // A stream of each `String` object in the array.
    .mapToLong( s -> s.codePoints().count() )  // Get the count of code points for each string. Returns a `LongStream`. 
    .toArray() ;                               // Returns an array of `long` primitives.
```

## Code points

Your code snippet and the other Answers use `String#length`. Unfortunately that method is legacy, based on the legacy type `char`.

That approach fails with most characters. Here is a demonstration of such a failure.

```
String input = "AC" ;
int len = input.length() ;
System.out.println( len ) ;
```

See that [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/I5tU0j).

> 4

Result is incorrect, reporting “4” for a string of 3 characters.

Instead of `char`, use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers when working with individual characters. A code point is the number permanently assigned to each character defined in Unicode.

For each string of our stream of inputs, get an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) whose elements are the code points of each character in that string. Get the count of that stream of code points, which returns a `long`.  Report those code point counts as a `LongStream`. Collect results to an array of `long` primitive values.

```
    String[] inputs = { "hello" , "bye" ,  "AC" } ;
    long[] lengths =
        Arrays
            .stream( inputs )                          // A stream of each `String` object in the array.
            .mapToLong( s -> s.codePoints().count() )  // Get the count of code points for each string. Returns a `LongStream`. 
            .toArray() ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/RQ24dD).

> [5, 3, 3]

Comment: That wouldn’t help you with `"‍"`, for example. Or just `"a̓"`.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply collect after mapping to `String::length`:

```
List<Integer> length = Arrays.stream(text)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(String::length)
    .toList();
```

This would give you a list with the lengths in the same order as defined in the array. (If below JDK 16, you need to use `collect(Collectors.toList())` instead of `toList()`).

Another option would be to collect to a `Map`:

```
Map<String, Integer> stringToLength = Arrays.stream(text)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), String::length));
```

This would give you a map with the strings as keys, and the length as values. `distinct()` is used in order to protect yourself from multiple copies of the same string, the map collecting would throw an exception in case of duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are starting with an array you may want to return an array so this will work.

```
String[] text = {"hello", "bye"};

int[] lengths = Arrays.stream(text)
    .mapToInt(String::length)
    .toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lengths));
```

prints

```
[5, 3]
```